# How to change Log Analytics Workspace of a Container App

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-container-apps

The `Log Analytics Workspace` of one of my `Container Apps` has been deleted.
So, when trying to access `Logs`:

[image]

I get a 404:

[image]

---

Is there a way to add a new `Workspace` to my `Container App`?

Answer (score 2):

Along with your Azure Container App,  ***Azure Container Apps
Environment is created that hosts the Azure Container App. Visit the Azure Container Apps Environment and change the Log Analytics Workspace via the Logging Options*** like below:-

[image]

***Select your another existing Log Analytics Workspace and Save the settings:-***

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Log storage and monitoring options in Azure Container Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/log-options#configure-options-via-the-azure-portal)